# Loading icon for Extjs olive theme

Tags: extjs

How to create extjs loading icon for olive theme.
   I tried it in http://www.ajaxload.info. It doesn't have that shape.

Regards,
Das

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no default "loading" icon inside the [Olive Theme](http://dev.extjs.com/learn/Extension:OliveTheme), so you'll need to define the location of a loading icon yourself.